# Filter rows with overlapping region

Tags: r

How can i remove a row in which the start and end of one row overlaps with other row in the same chr? –

```
   R_level  logp   chr start   end     CNA    Gene
        2   7.0    1  1159    4360    gain   Recl,Bcl
        1   2.4    1  1101    3689    gain   Bc1
        4   1.9    2  7180    9229    loss   Sox1,Tert
        2   4.5    2  8159    8360    loss   Sox1
        1   2.9    2  9154    10588   loss   Pekg
```

I want output some thing like this

```
R_level  logp   chr start   end     CNA    Gene
    2   7.0    1  1159    4360    gain   Recl,Bcl
    4   1.9    2  7180    9229    loss   Sox1,Tert
    1   2.9    2  9154    10588   loss   Pekg
```

Comment: You want to groupby(chr), then within each group, exclude any rows whose start and end values are within those of any other row in the same group?

Comment: The question seems ambiguous to me. Having two overlapping rows, which one would you like to remove?

Comment: can you give the wanted output?

Comment: @ Colonel Beauvel i hav updated the question..

Comment: why is row number two gone? and if you want to remove regions that have any overlap, how do you choose between removing row one and row two?

Comment: You still have overlapping rows within the same `chr` in your output! (compare rows 2 and 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems to be biology, you could use the `IRanges` package from `Bioconductors`:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
library(IRanges)

df<-yourDataFrame
data<-RangedData(IRanges(df$start,df$end),df[,-c(3,4,5)],space=df$chr)
data[!(countOverlaps(data,type=c("within"))@unlistData>1),]
```

Comment: @NicE...when i used IRanges got an error :                                     Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'countOverlaps' for signature '"standardGeneric", "standardGeneric"'